# Using database-like operators on a JSON file C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a slight issue with a web application that is using a JSON file as a temporary datastore. Basically, the problem is as follows:

The JSON file is being written to in real time. It is an array of objects serialized by a C# app. The data will then, also in real time (at some interval) be read from the JSON file by another program, deserialized, modified, and committed to a database.

When this step happens, I want to change a property of each object to indicate that it has been sent to the database. This way, other people that have access to the file, but not the database, can see what records have been committed. Additionally, it will allow for the second program to only index values that have not been committed in the future.

However, the issue emerges from the fact that both of these processes occur in real-time. In the second program, the entire JSON file is deserialized, modified and then overwritten. This means that if a record happens to be submitted as the second process is running, it will be lost.

I need a way to index the objects in the JSON file individually, inline with the file in C# to avoid this issue.

Comment: So you want database-like functionality without using a database? Hm, may I suggest you use a database?

Comment: Accessing one file while it's being modified by multiple applications is a bad idea. I'd suggest using SQLite. It will not require any installation and will be pretty much the same things, except it's a real database.

Comment: Or use that old and oscure technique of the `lock` file. If it is present, the process cannot use the file, if it is present, the process can use the file. You don't need to put anything in it and the filesystem will ensure it's uniqueness.

Comment: Why don't you take a differential approach, and have the second application create a copy of the JSON file, perform its work on that, and then when it's done, send a message to the first application and have it merge the changes into the active JSON file?

Comment: I can not use a database because of institutional red-tape. Trust me, I have pushed for a database for this step... I need an alternate solution still using JSON

Comment: @Stan SQLite is no good. It too only allows one process to write to a database file at a time.

Comment: How about a service that acts like a "database" reader. This one will handle all of the data access and then the 2 main applications can make calls to it.

Comment: Use a separate file to store the additional information that you would add to the original file

Comment: @aardvark, I think that'll do it. I just have to look into JSON.net's merge functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I think the suggestion made by @Andrew is the most elegant, if that's doable.